# Simultaneously ping code slows down and breaks as computer up time increases. What's going on?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, macos, ping, icmp

I have Python code that works with multiple IoT devices.  I can ssh into many of them simultaneously with no issues (using pexpect library).  This is done in a multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool.  Right after rebooting my MacBook, pinging multiple hosts in a thread pool also works fine.  Pinging 55 live hosts once each takes about a second and ping times are as expected.  However, as time goes on, things start working poorly for the ping code.  Ping times increase until the later-starting threads get timeouts.  The first threads to start succeed with reasonable ping times, but the wall time for the ping operation is very long--several seconds to return a ping time of under 100ms.

I simplified some test code to isolate the problem:

```
import subprocess
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
import pythonping
import ping3

# ping using a subprocess and ping command
def ping_1(ip):
    a = time.time()
    cmd = ['ping', '-c 1', '-W 2000', ip]
    result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, check=False)
    b = time.time()
    res = result.stdout.decode('utf-8')
    idx = res.find('time=')+len('time=')
    rtt = res[idx:res.find(' ', idx)]
    if not rtt and result.returncode == 0:
        print(res)
    rtt = '0' if not rtt else rtt
    return a, b, result.returncode == 0, float(rtt)

# ping using pythonping library
def ping_2(ip):
    a = time.time()
    result = pythonping.ping(ip, count=1, timeout=2.0)
    b = time.time()
    return a, b, result.success(), result.rtt_avg*1000

# ping using ping3 library
def ping_3(ip):
    a = time.time()
    result = ping3.ping(ip, timeout=2.0)
    b = time.time()
    return a, b, result is not None, result*1000 if result else result

# a dummy function to make sure threading works
def ding(_):
    a = time.time()
    time.sleep(1)
    b = time.time()
    return a, b

# executes one of the above in a thread pool
def test(func, ip_list, n_proc=20):
    start_time = time.time()
    if n_proc == 0:
        result = map(func, ip_list)
    else:
        with Pool(processes=n_proc) as pool:
            result = pool.map(func, ip_list)
    print(f'{f"start(s)":>8}  {f"end(s)":>6}  {"success":>7}  {"ping time (ms)":>14}')
    for start, end, success, ping_ms in result:
        print(f'{f"{start-start_time:0.3f}":>8}  {f"{end-start_time:0.3f}":>6}  '
            f'{str(success):>7}  {round(ping_ms):>14}')

# ping using n non-blocking subprocesses
def test2(ip_list):
    procs = [subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c 1', '-W 2000', ip]) for ip in ip_list]
    while any(proc.poll() is None for proc in procs):
        time.sleep(0.1)
    return [proc.poll() for proc in procs]
```

After a reboot, I get output that looks like the following.

```
>>> junk.test(junk.ping_1, ips, 30)
start(s)  end(s)  success  ping time (ms)
   0.020   0.071     True              31
   0.021   0.115     True              58
   0.026   0.118     True              32
   0.029   0.079     True              34
   0.031   0.098     True              32
   0.041   0.097     True              31
   0.051   0.141     True              55
   0.054   0.142     True              33
   0.071   0.288     True              56
   0.072   0.141     True              29
   0.079   0.133     True              30
   0.087   0.190     True              35
   0.098   0.184     True              32
   0.098   0.256     True              32
   0.098   0.308     True              30
   0.115   0.213     True              35
   0.118   0.307     True              36
   0.140   0.394     True              51
   0.141   0.264     True              53
   0.141   0.235     True              36
   0.142   0.412     True              36
   0.142   0.236     True              27
   0.142   0.270     True              33
   0.142   0.186     True              28
   0.148   0.247     True              31
   0.163   0.253     True              34
   0.176   0.353     True              33
   0.184   0.401     True              30
   0.185   0.333     True              32
   0.186   0.347     True              32
   0.190   0.441     True              56
   0.213   0.353     True              34
   0.221   0.386     True              32
   0.235   0.344     True              35
   0.236   0.374     True              56
   0.248   0.307     True              32
   0.248   0.447     True              51
   0.253   0.447     True              31
   0.256   0.423     True              29
   0.264   0.321     True              32
   0.270   0.412     True              51
   0.288   0.449     True              32
   0.303   0.443     True              34
   0.307   0.368     True              31
   0.307   0.380     True              30
   0.308   0.472     True              32
   0.314   0.458     True              33
   0.321   0.434     True              29
   0.333   0.452     True              30
   0.337   0.448     True              28
   0.344   0.412     True              29
   0.347   0.448     True              33
   0.353   0.442     True              28
   0.353   0.501     True              55
   0.371   0.464     True              34
```

After a few hours to a few days of uptime, it gradually becomes this:

```
start(s)  end(s)  success  ping time (ms)
   0.005   0.084     True              48
   0.005  10.217     True              39
   0.009  10.242     True              44
   0.012  10.207     True              51
   0.013  10.156     True             171
   0.029  10.217     True              50
   0.035  10.177     True              48
   0.053  10.157     True             166
   0.060  10.216     True             483
   0.061  10.124     True             689
   0.061  10.091     True             944
   0.085  10.111     True             945
   0.086  10.121     True             684
   0.095  10.100     True             955
   0.113  10.089     True             950
   0.126  10.117     True             959
   0.136  10.150     True             966
   0.136  10.141     True             964
   0.147   9.283     True            1003
   0.147  10.176     True             973
   0.148   9.245     True            1009
   0.148  10.175     True             976
   0.164  10.231     True             980
   0.173  10.177     True             973
   0.179  10.236     True             983
   0.194   9.276     True             997
   0.203   9.257     True            1000
   0.219   9.721     True            1470
   0.220   9.247     True            1007
   0.245   9.934     True            1960
   0.238   9.945     True            1947
   9.246  13.269    False               0
   9.247  13.271    False               0
   9.257  13.282    False               0
   9.277  13.291    False               0
   9.283  13.303    False               0
   9.722  13.747    False               0
   9.935  13.954    False               0
   9.945  13.967    False               0
  10.090  14.107    False               0
  10.091  14.116    False               0
  10.101  14.126    False               0
  10.111  14.136    False               0
  10.117  14.153    False               0
  10.121  14.153    False               0
  10.125  14.236    False               0
  10.142  14.170    False               0
  10.151  14.163    False               0
  10.156  14.187    False               0
  10.157  14.213    False               0
  10.175  14.247    False               0
  10.176  14.205    False               0
  10.177  14.219    False               0
  10.177  14.191    False               0
  10.207  14.230    False               0
```

All of the ping methods in the above code follow the same pattern.  (ping3 seems to behave strangely even after a reboot, but it still gets much worse over time.)  I've tried this over WiFi, wired Ethernet, and through my phone's hotspot feature.  I've tried restarting all Python kernels, upgrading Python (via Anaconda), upgrading MacOS (both major and minor), upgrading the VPN client (Cisco), removing antivirus software (MS Defender).  Nothing fixes it once it has gotten into this state except a reboot.  The pattern persists through all the listed updates.

Interestingly, while the computer is in this state, I can start up a Docker container and run the same code with the same Python version and it works great.  Shutting down Docker Desktop neither fixes the problem nor prevents it if done immediately after reboot.

I have also observed the operation of Angry IP Scanner (set to use 128 threads).  Right after a reboot, a particular IP scan takes 14 seconds.  After the ping problem has set in, the same scan takes 145 seconds!

I tried pinging my router 30 times in parallel and the problem shows up there, too, albeit to a much lesser degree.  Instead of pings timing out, they just get longer for the later-starting threads.  The first thread gets a ping in <10ms.  The last thread measures the ping time in the hundreds of milliseconds.

Update1:  Before going to bed last night, I ran the scan with Angry IP Scanner and it took about 15 seconds.  This morning it's taking 90 seconds.  The problem seems to have manifested while the computer is not in use.

Update2:  Again, the problem has cropped up while I was away from the computer.  Could it have something to do with the Mac's power-saving features?  During both of these recent occurrences, the MacBook was connected to AC power, so the power-saving features were partially disabled ("Prevent Mac from automatically sleeping when the display is off" is enabled in settings).

Comment: Not sure if its an issue, but, ... `[proc.poll() for proc in procs]` may be leaving a bunch of zombie processes in the OS. Do `[proc.wait(timeout=0) for proc in procs]` instead. You could likely do the wait instead of poll in the loop above by decreasing timeout as the waits return.

Comment: Have you tried removing the VPN entirely, so you're just running the "stock" macOS IP stack? Also, if you leave the Mac up for quite a while *before* running this test, does it show the problem on the first test, or only after several tests have been run?

Comment: @GordonDavisson, I have not tried that.  My work demands this kind of operation pretty frequently--not using the above test code, but the scripts from which it was distilled--so it would be difficult to do the test.  That's a good idea, though.  (The _real_ code uses Python's regular GIL-limited threadpool and the subprocess call like in ping_1() above.)

Comment: @tdelaney, thanks for the tip.  My real code does not use the non-blocking subprocess with `proc.poll`.  I only added that as a test after the problem had manifested itself many times to make sure it wasn't a problem with Python's threadpool.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with the Cisco VPN software.  Not the client itself, but some auxiliary extensions that go with it called packet filters.  Since they are system network extensions, they are active even when the VPN is disconnected.  A bug was introduced (or reintroduced) in version 4.10 of Cisco AnyConnect for MacOS and persists in version 5.0 (renamed Cisco Secure Client).  It causes very high CPU load (pegging one processor core on my system) during network activity, especially parallel operations such as occur during host scans.  The performance problem is so severe that Angry IP Scanner, for instance, can take 10x longer than normal to scan 200 IP addresses and will fail to detect *any* of the ports open on the hosts it finds.

The solution is to shutdown the packet filters and then delete the software.  As mentioned in [this post](https://community.cisco.com/t5/cisco-software-discussions/bug-cisco-anyconnect-4-10-high-cpu-usage-on-macos/td-p/4717551), deactivation is accomplished with the following console command:

`sudo /Applications/Cisco/Cisco\ AnyConnect\ Socket\ Filter.app/Contents/MacOS/Cisco\ AnyConnect\ Socket\ Filter -deactivateExt`.

The path is slightly different for Cisco Secure Client:

`sudo /Applications/Cisco/Cisco\ Secure\ Client\ -\ Socket\ Filter.app/Contents/MacOS/Cisco\ Secure\ Client\ -\ Socket\ Filter -deactivateExt`

Once that is done, trash the packet filter app under Applications/Cisco.  VPN connectivity seems to work fine without it.